# setting a synthetica look and feel in java

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel, synthetica

I'm using Netbeans as the IDE. I want to use `SyntheticaOrangeMetallicLookAndFeel`. I added the jar files to library. The following code segment is before the `initcomponents()` line inside the constructor.

```
   try{
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaOrangeMetallicLookAndFeel());
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

I'm getting this error while executing:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/swing/plaf/synth/SynthUI.

Help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Java7 together with an outdated Synthetica release. Use Java 6 or better a recent Synthetica release with Java 7 support.

Comment: you are right. I just added the latest Synthetica.jar and that worked